# How to show date in different language in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to show the date in a different language. But the date is stored in the database in English. But I want to show the date in a different language. But I don't know how to do that. Anyone please help.

```
<p  style="font-size: xx-small;">{{news.createdAt | date}}</p>
```

The output is coming like this `Mar 7, 2020`.
The expected output that I want is: `মার্চ ২৩, ২০২০`. The number and date everything is showing in different language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe), and specify locale you want to use :

```js
{{ news.createdAt | date:'medium':'+0200':'fr_FR' }}
```

First [as described in official doc](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes), you have to register each optional locales you will use with this pipe :

app.module.ts:

```js
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

// the second parameter 'fr-FR' is optional
registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr-FR');
```

Comment: Only the month is showing in different language. but the year, date, and time are showing in English.

Comment: What do you mean by year is showing in English ? Could you provide your output in your question, please.